# BiRT latest Runtime as one Maven Dependency for Eclipse

Tags: birt

I have a given eclipse maven project which builds to a jar. The pom has one major dependency of BiRT 4.8.0-202010080643 Runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.customer.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0-202010080643</version>
</dependency>
```

So they pushed the artifact into their own nexus; thats why com.customer.birt.runtime.
I really don't know how the guy did that and which tools he used. Currently I want to update to BiRT 4.9. Replacing the above with the only available:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
  <artifactId>birt-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency
```

does not go well. Both are totally different constellations from the same big project. How can I make use of the above maven dependency of 4.9 in my simple birt project? I'm building only a service for a desktop application that is hosted and run within an RCP application. I started to list the individual maven deps so that the java compiles which I succeeded to but I still have few unit tests that execute and render ReportEngine and fail because of missing Deps at runtime. This is because the ReportEngine is loading APIs at runtime..

I started to post here once I noticed that I will be declaring the separate deps in pom.xml blindly which is (even if the Unittests pass) very unreliable..

Thank you so much!

M.Abdu

Comment: A pom import is really just a way to have [managed dependency versions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#:~:text=The%20project%20that%20follows%20shows%20how%20the%20library%20can%20now%20be%20used%20in%20another%20project%20without%20having%20to%20specify%20the%20dependent%20project%27s). You still have to include relevant dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot guarantee all the relevant dependencies. BiRT simple use case (load .rptdesign into pdf, getContent,..) uses reflection, lazy loading, (you name it) at runtime. I got my maven build through but the very trivial unit test showed I have plenty of ClassNoFndExeption.. Unlike in eclipse and p2 in Target

Comment: I think my trail would be to (1) load the zip (2) unzip (3) pick org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.9.0-20220502.jar (4) intsall it to maven repo. That would be a nice thing to be done using maven and hopefully no Ant

Answer (score 0):

My solution was currently as I put in the comments or yet simpler. I just uploaded manually the birt-runtime jar into nexus using my account within the customer and then put in my pom the exact same **unique** coordinates groupid:artifactid:version. Plus some other dependencies depending of what my unit tests are asking at runtime, e.g. eclipse.platform, emf.core, w3c, batik.css etc.

I am talking about executing the build using **mvn clean verify** and resulting a jar file

The jar you get from here
https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/eclipse/birt/birt-runtime/4.9.0/birt-runtime-4.9.0.zip

pom in my case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
    <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.0-20220502</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Working with `XML` data source?

Comment: Can we use BIRT with IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 0):

in case someone gets here via google, I created a project to build the BIRT runtime maven artifact for Birt 4.14.0. see [the git repository](https://gist.github.com/ChangdongLi/f354b36ed5f1b92bbb333b811860e0e3)