# How to incorporate BIRT 4.9.0 into POM?

Tags: maven, birt

**Scenario:**

I am refactoring my application to work under java 17. Birt runtime 3.7.x is embedded in my application.

In updating to point to birt 4.9.0, I have updated my pom as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
            <artifactId>birt-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt/birt-runtime-osgi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
            <artifactId>birt-runtime-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I build,  I get the exception

```
org.eclipse.birt:birt-runtime:jar:4.9.0 was not found in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 during a previous attempt
```

I have deleted and rebuilt my local .m2 directory.

When I dig around the maven repository I find the file at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/birt/birt-runtime/4.9.0/

This link ([BiRT latest Runtime as one Maven Dependency for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532704/birt-latest-runtime-as-one-maven-dependency-for-eclipse/72556984#72556984)) was resolved by manually downloading the file and pointing to a local copy.  I'd prefer to avoid that, since Maven is all about avoiding that kind of scenario.

I suspect there's something in the maven path I am missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I found for BIRT 4.4.2 which worked for me.

[Add specific plugins and config when using Birt with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593124/add-specific-plugins-and-config-when-using-birt-with-maven)

**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.icu</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.v20140312-2051</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.icu</artifactId>
    <version>52.1.1.v201501240615</version>
</dependency>
```

**